# SQL: Looping through a column, stored the value as a variable, run SQL, then move on to the next line?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm currently shifting roles at my job and trying to teach myself some SQL Skills.

Scenario: I'm in charge of 1 database - 10 tables with 10 Primary Keys. Every month, our code team publishes updates to the tables. I am suppose to drop the tables and generate scripts to create the updated tables.

Rather than just drop the old tables and stored procedures, I want to rename my current tables to preserve the structure/data for whatever reason.

In my database, I have an additional table called "TableUpdateList" with 1 column "TableName" and 10 rows - each row containing the name of the updated column (Row 1 = TableName1, Row 2 = TableName2, Row 3 = TableName3)

I would like to be able to "loop" through the TableUpdateList Table and insert each value into a set of SQL statements.

For Example, here are the SQL statements I want to run:

```
--drop the previous backup table
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_NAME = '*TableName1*'+'_Old') DROP TABLE TableName1_Old

-- rename the current tables to _old 
EXEC sp_rename *TableName1*, TableName1_Old;
```

I'm trying to find a way to scroll through the column of my TableUpdateList and run the above two statements filling in where I've italicized with whatever value is present in that row.

Just taking a wild stab because I think in order to get an answer here, you have to try something so here is my pseudo-code:

```
Declare @TableNames as List

For i in @TableNames

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_NAME = '*i*'+'_Old') DROP TABLE TableName1_Old

-- rename the current tables to _old 
EXEC sp_rename *i*, TableName1_Old;
```

Oi, thanks in advance for any help or a point in the right direction to where I could do some further reading about the above online.

Comment: I'm unsure what your question actually is?

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen: I assume it's the "I'm trying to find a way to scroll through the column of my TableUpdateList and run the above two statements filling in where I've italicized with whatever value is present in that row" part. (Or if you prefer question syntax: "How can I scroll through the column of my TableUpdateList and run the above two statements filling in where I've italicized with whatever value is present in that row?".)

Comment: Take a look at the WHILE syntax. That might help.

Comment: So you want to loop through your `tablename` list and drop the old table and rename the current table as `_old`. Is that correct ? Is that case then as @Allen suggested take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms178642.aspx. In case of issue update here.

Comment: Can you provide a sample code contained in the variable @TableNames.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sp_executesql` with `CURSORS` for such type of work. Here is what i think you need:

Test objects:

```
CREATE TABLE TableName1 ( ID INT )
GO
CREATE TABLE TableName2 ( ID INT )
GO
CREATE TABLE TableNames ( Name NVARCHAR(MAX) )
GO

INSERT  INTO TableNames
VALUES  ( 'TableName1' ),
        ( 'TableName2' )
```

Script itself:

```
DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
    @dropStatement NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @renameStatement NVARCHAR(MAX)  

DECLARE cur CURSOR FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY
FOR
    SELECT  Name
    FROM    dbo.TableNames

OPEN cur

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

        IF EXISTS ( SELECT  *
                    FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
                    WHERE   TABLE_NAME = @name + '_Old' )
            BEGIN
                SET @dropStatement = 'DROP TABLE ' + @name + '_Old'
                EXEC sp_executesql  @dropStatement                  
            END

            SET @renameStatement = 'sp_rename ' + @name + ', ' + @name + '_Old';   
                EXEC sp_executesql  @renameStatement

        FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @name

    END

CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur
```

After this you should add `TableName1` and `TableName2` again.

Answer (score 0):

Cursors must be avoided as long as possible.

```
--Preparing script which would check if the old tables exists. If it does,
--it drops the old table
--e.g. first the value 'Table1' is found in TableUpdateList table.
--Then, Table1_Old is deleted and Table1 is renamed to Table1_Old

SELECT 'DROP TABLE ' + b.name + '_Old; EXEC sp_rename ''' + b.name+ ''', ''' + b.name+ '_Old;''' AS [Action] 
INTO #Action
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES A JOIN TableUpdateList B ON A.TABLE_NAME = b.NAME + '_Old'

DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(8000) 
SELECT @sql = COALESCE(@sql + ' ', '') + [Action]
FROM #Action

select @sql
--EXEC (@sql)
```

First verify the value of variable `@sql`. Then, uncomment the last line to execute the code.

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ad2bd/2)